# Regex pattern behaving differently in TCL compared with Perl & Python

Tags: python, perl, tcl, tclsh

I am trying to extract a sub-string from a string using regular expressions. Below is the working code in `Python` (giving desired results)

**Python Solution**

```
x = r'CAR_2_ABC_547_d'
>>> spattern = re.compile("CAR_.*?_(.*)")
>>> spattern.search(x).group(1)
'ABC_547_d'
>>>
```

**Perl Solution**

```
$ echo "CAR_2_ABC_547_d" | perl -pe's/CAR_.*?_(.*)/$1/'
ABC_547_d
```

**TCL Solution**

However, when I try to utilize this approach in `Tcl`, it is giving me different results. Can someone please comment on this behavior

```
% regexp -inline "CAR_.*?_(.*)" "CAR_2_ABC_547_d"
CAR_2_ {}
```

Answer (score 4):

> A branch has the same preference as the first quantified atom in it
>   which has a preference.

So if you have `.*` as the first quantifier, the whole RE will be greedy,
and if you have `.*?` as the first quantifier, the whole RE will be non-greedy.

Since you have used the `.*?` in the first place itself, the further expression follow lazy mode only.

If you add end of line `$`, then it will match the whole.

```
% regexp -inline "CAR_.*?_(.*)$" "CAR_2_ABC_547_d"
CAR_2_ABC_547_d ABC_547_d
```

**Reference :** [re_syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M95)

Comment: my requirement is to extract the sub-string "ABC_547_d". I have deliberately used `?` to make it non greedy. I just want to understand why it works in Python and not TCL

Comment: This is with respect to `Tcl`.  Since the first quantifier is non-greedy, the `.*` will only match empty string. If you have used `.+`, then it will give you the letter `A` alone.

Comment: Can you please suggest on how to achieve the desired result using Tcl regex with grouping method. I can see the original regex working in Perl and Python. Does TCL handles regex differently?

Comment: @sarbjit Python and Tcl use different regex engines. (Perl's is also different, but Python's is derived from the Perl one by a complicated route.)

Comment: @Dinesh: That is complete nonsense. `.*?` can't match the empty string because the pattern requires that it is followed by an underscore.

Comment: @Borodin, Dinesh is referring to the capturing `(.*)` which, since it is implicitly non-greedy, will match the empty string following the second underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, instead of capturing the text that follows the prefix, is to just remove the prefix:

```
% set result [regsub {^CAR_.*?_} "CAR_2_ABC_547_d" {}]
ABC_547_d
```